# git: libcrypto.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: git, shared-library

All of a sudden I get this error now when trying to run git. Installed git version is 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.2. Does anyone have this problem too? Any ideas how to fix it (i.e. where to get libcrypto.so.1.0.2 from)? Ubuntu 16.04

```
$ lsb_release -sd
Ubuntu 16.04.3 LTS
$ apt policy git libssl1.0.0
git:
  Installed: 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1.2 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:2.7.4-0ubuntu1 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
libssl1.0.0:
  Installed: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
  Candidate: 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8
  Version table:
 *** 1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.8 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.0.2g-1ubuntu4.6 500
        500 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.0.2g-1ubuntu4 500
        500 http://de.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
```

Comment: Can you please add the outputs of `lsb_release -sd` and `apt policy git libssl1.0.0`? It is odd that you need `libcrypto.so.1.0.2`, because 16.04 only has version 1.0.0.

Comment: I have added the output to the question

Comment: Would you add the full `git` command and its output as well as the output of `which git`? Also you could try to `sudo apt install --reinstall git libssl1.0.0`, but I am not sure if that will help. The problem is that all of Ubuntu's `libssl` packages are internally in version 1.0.2, but still have 1.0.0 in their package and file names. Could you maybe have any additional git installations that are not from the Ubuntu repositories, maybe something project-specific or local in your home directory?

Comment: full command is just "git" or basically any invocation of git fails and the full error is "git: error while loading shared libraries: libcrypto.so.1.0.2: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory". Reinstall of libssl didn't help.  Also if I try to "locate libcrypto.so" I get the following entries: /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0, /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so,  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.1

Comment: Installed git from source and now it's working